# Como especificar que o tipo do construtor seja igual ao declarado na classe?

Tags: java, genéricos

Criei um um objeto que aceita uma lista de qualquer tipo, assim:

```
class Grid<T> {
    private Integer count;
    private Integer offset;
    private Integer limit;
    private List<T> list;

    private T tipo;

    public Grid() {
    }

    public Grid(Integer count, List<T> list) {
        this.count = count;
        this.list = list;
    }
}
```

Porém, dessa maneira ele me permite criar um objeto de um tipo e passar no construtor outro tipo, assim:

```
List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);
```

Ou seja, criei um Grid do tipo `Empresa`, e passei no construtor uma lista do tipo `Usuario`.

Já se fizer um `setList(List<T> list)` ele funciona como esperado, ou seja, ele só aceita se a lista for do mesmo tipo da declarada na classe.

**Como posso exigir que a lista do construtor seja igual àquela declarada na classe?** Ou seja, se criar um `Grid<Empresa>` no construtor ele só deva aceitar uma lista do tipo `List<Empresa>`.

Comment: Ô loco. Tem certeza disto? Não conheço Java tão a fundo para falar sobre isto, mas pra mim esta forma está correta e deveria restringir. Eu imagino que estou errado e alguém vai dizer o que tem que fazer.

Comment: Esta forma é a correta. Talvez você esteja estranhando o fato da IDE não acusar como erro de compilação, o que de fato, não é mesmo. Tente rodar seu programa exatamente como mostrou e verá que será lançado uma exceção referente ao tipo informado ser diferente.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe, apenas instanciando dessa forma não deu erro nem de compilação nem de execução. Porém, ao tentar buscar um item da lista, deu erro de Cast, o que é correto...

Comment: Você viu que está usando `List ` e não `ArrayList`? De qualquer forma que tal fazer um MCVE?

Comment: @bigown creio que este nem seja o problema, pois Arraylist implementa List, então não está incorreto. Pelo que eu entendi, ele quer barrar no construtor passar uma lista de um tipo diferente, o único jeito que eu conheço de fazer isso é usando interface, mas como não domino muito bem interfaces, talvez alguém com mais experiencia possa explicar melhor.

Comment: Também não acho e não acho que interface tenha a ver com isso.

Comment: @Earendul da uma olhada neste arquivo, vê se é isto atende ao seu problema. http://www.inf.pucrs.br/flash/alpro2/present/U03_projeto/01b-genericos/handout.html#genéricos

Comment: Fiz um teste e realmente acontece. Que bela porcaria. Fiz em C# e nem compila por causa do tipo estar errado. Agora quero ver como soluciona isto.

Comment: O Eclipse dá a seguinte informação `Type safety: The expression of type Grid needs unchecked conversion to conform to Grid<Empresa>` em `new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);`

Comment: @DiegoFelipe li o arquivo, mas ainda não sei como resolver o problema. Talvez só mesmo evitando receber a lista no construtor e apenas no set.

Comment: @ramaral E o Netbeans não avisa nada..

Comment: @bigown Também quero ver como soluciona isso, :)

Comment: Possivel causa do problema: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9366121/calling-constructor-of-a-generic-type Pelo que entendi, diz que no momento em que a classe é instanciada, o construtor é chamado, mas quando é inferido um tipo generico nesta classe, o tipo até então é desconhecido, então o java não tem como checar o tipo T pois até que o construtor seja finalizado, este tipo é desconhecido.

Comment: @bigown se seu inglês for bom, por favor, verifique este tópico no SOen, pela tradução instantânea, parece responder a este caso.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe isto eu já tinha percebido, até porque se pudesse, eles fariam, eu até imaginava qual era o motivo já que eles usam *type erasure*. O que eu quero saber é como resolver isto. Imagino que é fazer o que se faz em linguagem dinâmica. E tem gente que diz que Java é uma linguagem segura em tipos, principalmente quando se comprar com C#.

Comment: Uma luz no fim do túnel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1942644/get-generic-type-of-java-util-list/ Só não explico porque infelizmente ainda não aprendi reflexão em java(apesar deste tópico ser um incetivo para tal hehe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Você está criando a instância do "jeito errado"

> Você não está criando uma instância da sua classe *generic*, por isso o compilador está aceitando um tipo diferente no construtor sem acusar erro.

Esta maneira como você criou uma instância da sua classe:

```
Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid(...);
```

é permitida pelo compilador por motivo de retrocompatibilidade. Veja: [The Java Tutorials - Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

Em suma, apesar de você não ter nenhuma classe `Grid` pois o que você declarou foi `Grid<T>`, ou seja, um *generic*, o compilador considera que existe sim uma classe `Grid` e ele a chama de *raw type*. Ele precisa disso para compatibilidade com código antigo, anterior ao advento do *generics*

**Todavia, a forma de se criar uma instância de uma classe *generic* é esta:**

```
Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid<Empresa>(...);
```

<sub>*new Grid<Empresa>(...)* em vez de *new Grid(...)*</sub>

**Ou seja: você deveria informar o *generic parameter* na criação da instância**, senão você está na verdade criando uma instância do *raw type* e não uma instância da sua classe generic.

Se você criar corretamente uma instância da classe *generic* você terá um erro de compilação quando o tipo passado ao seu construtor não bater com o tipo do *generic parameter*.

Em **C#** (outra linguagem a suportar *generics*) não tem o tal do *raw type* de modo que você é obrigado a explicitar o *generic parameter* como eu fiz acima.

Em Java você também pode usar a sintaxe chamada *diamond <>*, deixando que o compilador infira o tipo do *generic parameter* a partir da declaração da variável:

```
Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid<>(...);
```

Se você seguir esta prática, explicitando o *generic parameter* ou usando a sintaxe *diamond*, será gerado um erro de compilação caso você tente usar uma instância de tipo incompatível com o *generic parameter* informado.

## Por que o NetBeans não alerta quanto à má prática?

Porque o *warning* do compilador quanto ao uso de *raw types* é desligado por padrão. Se você olhar os *hints* do compilador, entretanto, o aviso estará lá:

```
Note: Main.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
```

Se você ativar este warning no NetBeans (no Eclipse ele vem ativado por padrão), você será avisado pelo editor e também durante a compilação com a seguinte mensagem:

```
Grid is a raw type. References to generic type Grid 
should be parameterized.
```

```
Type safety: The constructor Grid(Integer, List) belongs to the raw type Grid. 
References to generic type Grid should be parameterized.
```

Você poderia inclusive tratar este *warning* como erro, impedindo a compilação quando fosse criado uma instância de um *raw type*.

Eu não tenho NetBeans instalado mas esta imagem mostra mais ou menos onde fica essa configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo. Instanciando dessa forma e com tipos diferentes o Netbeans já "xingou" antes mesmo de compilar...

Answer (score 1):

Pela pesquisa que fiz não é possível resolver essa questão em tempo de compilação.
No entanto o compilador(Eclipse) dá o seguinte *warning*:

> *Type safety: The expression of type Grid needs unchecked conversion to conform to Grid*

no código `new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);`

Esse comportamento está descrito na [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) no seguinte paragrafo:

> **Type Inference and Instantiation of Generic Classes**
>
> You can replace the type arguments required to invoke the constructor of a generic class with an empty set of type parameters (<>) as long as the compiler can infer the type arguments from the context. This pair of angle brackets is informally called the diamond.
>
> For example, consider the following variable declaration:
>
> `Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();`
>
> You can substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>):
>
> `Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<>();`
>
> Note that to take advantage of type inference during generic class instantiation, you must use the diamond. In the following example, the compiler generates an unchecked conversion warning because the HashMap() constructor refers to the HashMap raw type, not the `Map<String, List<String>>` type:
>
> `Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap(); // unchecked conversion warning`

Basicamente diz que o tipo dos argumentos requeridos para invocar o construtor de uma classe genérica pode ser substituído por um conjunto vazio de tipos de argumentos (<>) desde de que o compilador possa inferir o tipo através do contexto.
Caso não sejam indicados os tipos ou não seja utilizado `<>` o compilador gerará um ***unchecked conversion warning***

Se usar `Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid<>(10, listaUsuarios);` o compilador gerará o seguinte erro de compilação:

> Cannot infer type arguments for Grid<>

Explicando com exemplos:

- Tipos diferentes e sem utilizar `<>`

  ```
  List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
  Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);
  ```

  O compilador gera um *warning*:

  > *Type safety: The expression of type Grid needs unchecked conversion to conform to Grid*
- Tipos diferentes utilizando `<>`

  ```
  List<Usuario> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
  Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);
  ```

  O compilador gera um erro:

  > Cannot infer type arguments for `Grid<>`
- Tipos iguais e sem utilizar `<>`

  ```
  List<Empresa> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
  Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid(10, listaUsuarios);
  ```

  O compilador gera um *warning*:

  > *Type safety: The expression of type Grid needs unchecked conversion to conform to `Grid<Empresa>`*
- Tipos iguais utilizando `<>`

  ```
  List<Empresa> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();
  Grid<Empresa> grid = new Grid<>(10, listaUsuarios);
  ```

  O compilador fica "contente", sem erro e sem *warning*.